# What does (char)0 mean in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

What is the meaning of `(char)0`.

For example what does this mean?

```
array[1] = (char)0;
```

Comment: Assigns 0 to the array element? The cast is probably superflous.

Comment: Your question title says C++, but your tags include C. Which is it? (The answer differs, at least theoretically, based on language.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a C-style cast. That is, it converts `0` (which is a literal of type `int`) to `char` (the `\0` character). That cast could have been avoided entirely by simply using the `'\0'` literal.

Comment: what's the purpose of doing that?

Comment: Not in C, where `'\0'` has type `int`.

Comment: @dan04 The question says C++.

Comment: @Ravindu Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. My guess is that the programmer wanted to avoid a warning by assigning an `int` to a `char`, but using a cast instead of just a litteral seems overkill.

Comment: while(line.at(i) != '\t')
 {
  surname[j] = line.at(i);
  i++;
  j++;
 }
 surname[j] = (char)0;
 i++;
 j = 0;

Comment: @Ravindu Yeah, useless. Just use `'\0'` instead of `(char)0`. And if `line` is `std::string`, then use `operator[]` instead of `at()` if you're sure you'll never go out of bounds.

Comment: @Etienna what happens from '\0'??

Comment: @Ravindu `'\0'` is a character literal constant that is the null character (0 in ASCII).

Comment: means after i assigned '\0' to the last array position it won't print any garbage values for the rest of the array which i doesn't apply any values. right?

Comment: @Ravindu Well, it's zero, so, it's the end of a C string.

Answer (score 2):

It's `0` casted to a `char`, which is `'\0'`.

Comment: Generally nothing, since the typing between numbers (in the byte range) and characters is weak in C.

Answer (score 0):

You are *casting* an int (integer) (`0`) to a character (char).

Casting means you are changing the type.