# C++ replacing values in a dynamic 2D Array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to replace the '.' in my array with 'O'but it inserts it in between rather than taking its place. Please help I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char** createField(int w, int l)
{
    int obstacles;

    char ** arr = new char * [w];
    for(int i=0; i<w; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new char[l];
    }
//Initializing the values
    for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; ++j)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Enter number of obstacles: ";
    cin>>obstacles;

   int x=0;
   int y=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < obstacles; ++j) {
            cout<<"Enter location of obstacles: ";
            cin>>x>>y;
            arr[x][y] ='O';
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if(i==0 || i == w-1){
                cout<< arr[i][j]<< 'W';
            }else if(j==0 || j==l-1){
                cout<< arr[i][j]<< 'W';
            } else
                cout<< arr[i][j]<< '.';

        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }


    return arr;
}
int main() {
    int w;
    int l;

    cout << "Enter the Width: ";
    cin >> w;

    cout << "Enter the length: ";
    cin >> l;
//Pointer returned is stores in p
    char **p = createField(w, l);


//Do not Forget to delete the memory allocated.It can cause a memory leak.
    for (int del = 0; del < w; del++) {
        delete[] p[del];
    }
    delete[]p;
}
```

Here is an example of my output, I want the 'O' to replace the '.' rather than be in between the two. Also if someone could explain why this is happening that would be really helpful Thanks.

Example of output: w.O.w
Desired output: w.Ow

Comment: First, i have a question: How many characters do you think `cout<< arr[i][j]<< '.'` will send to stdout ? Or how about `cout<< arr[i][j]<< 'W'` ?

Comment: its suppose to be a user inputted value so if the user enters 10 for width and 11 for length the array will adjust itself accordingly.

Comment: I'm not asking how many loop iterations; I'm just asking about the two statements each. *That's all*. Is it  1 ? 2 ? 3 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure just 1.  I'm still very new to programming so sorry if that's not accurate.

Comment: It's *two*. (Sorry, was watching a Hot Ones episode with guest Gordon Ramsey. Good lord that was FaF.). That means each and every time `cout<< arr[i][j]<< 'W'` or `cout<< arr[i][j]<< '.'` is executed, *two* characters are printed: the content in `a[i][j]`, and the trailing character `W` or `.`. Walk that on paper and see if it makes sense now, the output you're getting.

Comment: I am sorry as well, but you are using raw pointers for owned memory and C-Style arrays. You are using new and delete. You should (must) not use such language constructs. . .  And if it is an exercise in a C++ Class, the instructor should be fired.

Comment: If you use `vector` rather than manual memory management you will save a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

When you set arr[i][j] = 0, it will cast 0 into char before assigning it to arr[i][j]. 0 casts to the literal ['\0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004297/what-does-char0-mean-in-c) which means a [null character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183445/what-does-0-mean). Later when you print the contents of arr, the null characters cannot be seen in output which is part of the underlying cause of your confusion. Hope that explains what's going on a little bit better.